# Angular velocity of pinned rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

Below is a problem I'm not really sure If I'm doing it right...

[image]

As shown in the figure, two rods $PQ$ and $QR$, pinned at $Q$ and rod $QR$ is hinged at $R$. $P$ moves with a velocity $v_0$ and acceleration $a_0$ along the incline. We are required to find the angular velocities of $P$ and $Q$, angular acceleration of $PQ$ as well as $QR$.

My line of thinking is as follows:

$$\omega_{PQ} = \frac{v_{\perp}}{\ell} = \frac v\ell \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$
Similarly for rod $QR$, $$\omega_{QR} = \frac{v_{\perp}}{\ell} = \frac v\ell \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

***Is my reasoning correct?***

I'm bit confused (stuck) to find the angular acceleration of $PQ$.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your reasoning is that you assume for *PQ* that *Q* is not moving and the rod is purely rotating about *Q*. This is evident by you dividing by $\ell$ the velocitiy components.

To get the answer you need to find the **instant center of rotation** of each rod.

[image: pic1]

Rod $QR$ is pivoting about $R$ and the velocity of $Q$ is shown above with the blue arrow.

Find where there two perpendiculars of the velocities of $Q$ and $P$ meet to find the center of rotation of $QP$. To me it looks like it falls on $R$ on this instant.

This means the moment-arm of $QP$ is the distance between $RP$.

$$ \omega_{\rm QP} = \frac{ v_0 }{| RP |}$$

and similarly for the other links, and for accelerations.

Comment: Oh Yes! I can now see clearly that $R$ is the IAR for PQ. Thanks for your input!
I don't have enough rep to upvote...

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear diagram upon I can built on. Made the answer write itself.

Comment: :) It's really true, "A picture is worth a thousand words!"